# Find the area of the parallelogram given perimeter, one angle and the proportion of heights

Tags: geometry

Find the area of the parallelogram whose perimeter is $20$, one internal angle is $30^\circ$ and heights are in the proportion $2:3$.

---

*Setup*

So, the perimeter is $20$:
$$P=20$$
One angle is $30^\circ:$
$$\alpha=30^\circ$$
And heights are in the proportion $2:3$.
$$h_a:h_b=2:3$$
*What else do we know?*

Well, since the adjacent angles in a parallelogram are complementary for $180^\circ$, we know that the another angle is
$$\beta=180^\circ-30^\circ=150^\circ$$
We can also express heights in terms of each other:
$$h_a=\frac{2}{3}h_b$$
$$h_b=\frac{3}{2}h_a$$

---

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: The result must be the same computing the area either way, so: $a\cdot h_a=b\cdot h_b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use $$\sin30 = {h_a\over b} = {h_b\over a}$$

So $b= 2h_a = 4t$ and $a=2h_b = 6t$. Since $a+b = 10$ we get $10t = 10$ so $t=1$...